# Creating a frequency table in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table where different participants are given multiple boxes of medicines on multiple days. I am trying to create a frequency table showing how much medicines have been distributed by the number of boxes to the participants.
[image]

The result I'm looking for is -

2 boxes = 1 (since only Lynda got a total of 2 boxes), 4 boxes = 2 (since Ryan and Rinky both got a total of 4 boxes after adding up the medicine boxes)

Please let me know what approach would be the best in this case.
Thanks for your help.
-Nams

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. No participant got 4 boxes; where did "4" come from?  Use tables instead of a verbal description of tables, please.

Comment: when you say '4 boxes = 1' do you mean '1 box = 3', or that 1 box of medicine was given out 3 times, 1 to ABC today, 1 to XYZ today, and 1 to XYZ tomorrow?

Comment: edited the question, and added a table.
Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Please do not post images, actual data is much more useful as it can be used to test.

Comment: I can't post the actual data, since it contains some sensitive information, however, this is pretty much how the table looks like sans the demographic data that's in the table. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can post text, not an image. An image means that anyone who wants to test has to type your data, whereas you must have had the text to get the image. It makes things much easier for people trying to help you when you post text.

Comment: I don't use the site much, except when I'm in a dire need of help and can't find a solution to my question after wrapping my head around it for ages. When I did add the table to the question, it resulted in a line/sentence form, instead of the table form. I spent quite a while on understanding and writing up the question itself, adding the table seemed to take the last bit of my energy since I'm not too familiar with the format on here. So, please forgive my naive approach to asking questions, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.SumOf, Count(t.[PARTICIPANT ID]) AS CountOf
FROM (SELECT Table1.[PARTICIPANT ID], Sum(Table1.MEDICINE_BOX) AS SumOf
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[PARTICIPANT ID])  AS t
GROUP BY t.SumOf;
```

Where table1 is the name of your table.

Comment: edited the question to include the table, and the results I'm looking for.

Comment: That is what I thought you wanted and I believe that is what my query supplies.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is like this:

```
medicine_dispense
participantID   date    amount_boxes
ABC             8/29/12  1
ABC             8/30/12  2
XYZ             8/29/12  1
XYZ             8/30/12  1
```

then a query like this:

```
select
amount_boxes, count(participantID)
from
medicine_dispense
```

should work

Comment: Edited the question to include a table, and the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use generic SQL. You can paste SQL into Access queries in SQL view. (You might have to delete the CHECK() constraint.)

```
create table participant_meds (
  participant varchar(10) not null,
  distribution_date date not null default current_date,
  num_boxes integer not null check (num_boxes > 0),
  primary key (participant, distribution_date)
);

insert into participant_meds values ('Ryan', '2012-02-03', 1);
insert into participant_meds values ('Ryan', '2012-06-07', 3);
insert into participant_meds values ('Rinky', '2012-02-28', 4);
insert into participant_meds values ('Lynda', '2012-03-04', 2);
insert into participant_meds values ('Russ', '2012-04-05', 2);
insert into participant_meds values ('Russ', '2012-05-08', 2);
insert into participant_meds values ('Russ', '2012-06-12', 2);
```

Resulting data, sorted, for copy/paste.

```
participant distribution_date   num_boxes
Lynda   2012-03-04  2
Rinky   2012-02-28  4
Russ     2012-04-05 2
Russ     2012-05-08 2
Russ     2012-06-12 2
Ryan     2012-02-03 1
Ryan     2012-06-07 3
```

This query gives you the total boxes per participant.

```
select sum(num_boxes) boxes, participant
from participant_meds
group by participant;

6;"Russ"
2;"Lynda"
4;"Ryan"
4;"Rinky"
```

Use that query in the FROM clause as if it were a table.  (I'd consider storing that query as a view, because I suspect that the total number of boxes per participant might be useful. Also, Access has historically been good at optimizing queries that use views.)

```
select boxes num_boxes, count(participant) num_participants
from (select sum(num_boxes) boxes, participant
      from participant_meds
      group by participant) total_boxes
group by num_boxes
order by num_boxes;

num_boxes  num_participants
--
2          1
4          2
6          1
```

Comment: That is a lot of cutting and pasting. Access will only run one statement at a time.

Comment: The OP probably already has the data and just needs the query. I've just made it easier for others to answer.

Comment: Not in MS Access. You can cut and paste data straight into an MS Access table in one chunk, the above would require a minimum of 8 cut-and-paste and run query.

Comment: @Remou: Does that data I pasted work for copy/paste into Access? If not, what format would be better? CSV?

Comment: The resulting data works for me, because I have a little routine, but for a straight cut and paste into a table, you need field names and tabs, though it does depend on the version.

Comment: Looks wonky, but it preserved the tabs. Is this the best format for Access?

Comment: No the tabs do not translate. However, as far as posters are concerned, I would be happy with any text data, because I have routine that fixes dates, decimals, etc. Even if you don't Access will import text data very nicely from a text document, including your original output.

Comment: Hmm. SO preserved the tabs in edit view, but not in public view.

Comment: Yep. I cut from the edit window and it works fine, re-tested from the public window and no go.